# Overriding default interface methods

Tags: java, interface

I have found in Java Tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) this sample code:

```
public interface Flyer {
    default public String identifyMyself() { //<- the default modifier gives an error
        return "I am able to fly.";
    }
}
```

I tried to compile it but as I stated it eclipse gives me an error: `Syntax error on token "default", delete this token`.

My question is why I cannot run the above code? In fact I cannot run the whole example. Was the `default` modifier for interface methods introduced after some Java version (I am using 1.6 I think)?

Comment: Check that you use Java >= 8

Comment: I do not know if `public` is correctly placed. Anyway, methods in interfaces are `public` by default so they should never have public/private etc.

Comment: [Click](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) me...!!!!!

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Lamba but I cannot switch to Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java default method in interface is new feature in **java 8** :

Check Out http://java.dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was gonna ask some more questions about `default` methods, so it answered my questions.

Answer (score 3):

[Default interface methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) were [introduced in Java 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html).

Answer (score 1):

Default methods was introduced in Java 8, so they will not work in Java 6.